# use linq to write new file

Tags: c#, linq, filewriter

So I'm trying to make a new file based on information gained from an XDocument that I have

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"path.to.x.document");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(WriteFile);
        var variabila = (from x in doc.Descendants("sentence").Elements("word")
                      select new
                      {
                          lemma = x.Attribute("lemma")?.Value,
                          postag = x.Attribute("postag")?.Value
                      }).ToSOMETHING; //Here i need to store it to something so later I can use that something like this
```

In that SOMETHING lemma can have the same value for different postag also postag can have the same value for different lemma like this :

```
lemma="somf" postag="S321"
lemma="areq" postag="O213"
lemma="somf" postag="O213"
lemma="werid" postag="S321"
```

So I need to write to file like this .Basically if it's the end of a sentence it will go on a new line.

```
if(SOMETHING.lemma == "." || SOMETHING.lemma == "!")
{
    sw.WriteLine(SOMETHING.lemma);
}
else
{
    sw.Write(SOMETHING.lemma + " " + SOMETHING.postag);
}
```

I have tried with Lookup and dictionary but if I use dictionary I'm getting an exception since dictionary can't store the same key twice and lookup avoid that exception but I need them in the order they appear in order to form sentences based on lemma and postag only in the new file.

Comment: Have you tried using `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`?

Comment: Can you post an example please ?

Comment: @Jhon Jackson, it seems youv'e just de-accepted my answer. Is it not helpful any more? Does it still answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, was my mistake i randomly cliked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then, as an example, you'd have the following xml:

```
<root>
    <sentence>
       <word lemma="somf" postag="S321" />
       <word lemma="areq" postag="O213" />
       <word lemma="somf" postag="O213" />
       <word lemma="werid" postag="S321" />
       <word lemma="." postag="" />
    </sentence>
    <sentence>
       <word lemma="areq" postag="O213" />
       <word lemma="somf" postag="S321" />
       <word lemma="werid" postag="S321" />
       <word lemma="somf" postag="O213" />
       <word lemma="." postag="" />
    </sentence>
</root>
```

And you want your file to be written as:

```
somf S321 areq O213 somf O213 werid S321.
areq O213 somf S321 werid S321 somf O213.
```

Note that I assume you get a `.` or `!` as the last element, but you can play with it as required.

Then you can just iterate each `sentence` and its `word`s ([see the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mpi0Kz)):

```
using(StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter("result.txt"))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"path.to.x.document");
    var sentences = doc.Descendants("sentence");
    foreach (var sentence in sentences)
    {
        var line = string.Empty;
        var words = sentence.Elements("word");
        var lastWord = words.LastOrDefault();
        foreach (var word in words.Take(words.Count()-1))
        {
            line = string.join(
               " ",
               line,
               word.Attribute("lemma").Value,
               word.Attribute("postag").Value
            );
        }
        line = string.Join(string.Empty, line, lastWord.Attribute("lemma").Value);
        stream.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```